# Trying to place listbox in the middle of the page, with the scrollbar on the right

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

I'm using a listbox with a scrollbar with Tkinter in python. I'm trying to put the scrollbar on the right of the page and allow it to expand if the user expands the window, and also have the listbox placed in the middle of the window, but for some reason the listbox is just stretching to the right and bottom of the page permanently, even when its not expanded
Here's my code, thanks for any help in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk  

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,Task):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("1024x720")
        frame.configure(bg='#333130')


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        global listboxz
        listboxz = Listbox(self,height='500',width='400')
        listboxz.place(x=10, y=120)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        listboxz.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.configure(command=listboxz.yview)

class Task(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that `width` and `height` of `Listbox` specify the number of characters per line and number  of lines respectively, not the number of pixels.  Your listbox will be too big to fit in the window.

Answer (score 0):

To place something in the middle of the page with `place()` you need to use `relx` and `rely`, like this:

```
    listboxz.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='c')
```

Comment: thankyou very much, what do all of those do? relx, rely and anchor='c'

Comment: See [Place Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).